# Static Variable not Working Magento2 in php

Tags: php, class, magento2

```
class Traineelist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{ protected $categoryFactory;
   static protected $zcount=0;
.
.
. public static function staticBar () {
    return ++self::$zcount;
}
}
```

My zcount is not incremented on Every instance, its value remains "1".